# Configure Nexus connection for maven deployment

Tags: maven, teamcity, nexus

Im trying to gain some experience in working with Nexus and TeamCity.
To do so i set both servers up on my local machine and configured a pet project thats located on github.com in a private repo.

But i can't get my TC-Build to run because the Maven deploy step fails with following message.

```
[14:58:55][Step 2/2] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project Worm: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.test.worm:Worm:jar:1.0.0 from/to local_nexus (http://localhost:8081/repository/org.test): Transfer failed for http://localhost:8081/repository/org.test/org/test/worm/Worm/1.0.0/Worm-1.0.0.jar 401 Unauthorized
```

Seems like it fails due to wrongly configured authorization but i can't find the mistake.
In my projects pom.xml it is configured like this

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>local_nexus</id>
        <name>Deployment</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/org.test</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and in my mavens settings.xml like this

```
<server>
  <id>local_nexus</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

Im using the default admin user (user/pw is correct, logging into nexus with the same user) that is created when installing nexus. Same user that created the repository.

TC running under localhost:8080 and Nexus under localhost:8081
Please tell me what i configured wrongly or what i forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mvn help:effective-settings` i could confirm that the settings.xml was configured correctly. But it made me realize that my TeamCity Server was using a different (its own) maven instance than my local machine. So the solution was to either set the maven-home for TeamCity or to configure the settings.xml of the other maven instance.

Stupid mistake i should have noticed way sooner.